# Batch script that copies all files from an FTP folder

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I need a batch script that copies files from a FTP folder into another folder. It should backup the folder on the FTP afterwards and delete a original.

I've already gotten this far. It now does only copy a file to a folder.
How can I backup the folder on the FTP and delete it afterwards?

Thanks

```
@Echo Off
Set _FTPServerName=
Set _UserName=
Set _Password=
Set _LocalFolder=C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\
Set _RemoteFolder=Public\Testfolder\
Set _Filename=file.txt
Set _ScriptFile=ftp1
Set _BackupFolder=Public\Backup
:: Create script
 >"%_ScriptFile%" Echo open %_FTPServerName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_UserName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_Password%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo lcd %_LocalFolder%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo cd %_RemoteFolder%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo binary
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo get %_Filename%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo quit
:: Run script
ftp -s:"%_ScriptFile%"
Del "%_ScriptFile%"
```

Comment: You could place all the `echo` commands in a parenthesised block and redirect that once: `> "%_ScriptFile%" (` ... `echo ...` ... `echo ...` ... `)`...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`mget` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-mget):

```
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo mget *
```